# Не работает PagerAdapter

Tags: android

У меня есть `PagerAdapter` для `ViewPager`:

```
private class ViewPaggerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            View v = null;

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_one, null);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_two, null);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_three, null);
                    break;
            }

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Назначаю его так:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_viewPager_1);
viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter());
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Но эти три страницы у меня пустые (хотя там `TextView`)! Почему? И, как ни странно, слушатель перелистывания страниц работает.

Comment: А текст в поле есть? Может просто поле пустое...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, есть... Черный, точно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правило во ViewPager хранят фрагменты, а не Views. Правильный будет если ты их положишь во фрагменты. Вот простой пример рабочего адаптера ViewPager'a.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Context context;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new FragmentOne();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentTwo();
        case 2:
            return new FragmentThree();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return context.getString(R.string.tab_1);
        case 1:
            return context.getString(R.string.tab_2);
        case 2:
            return context.getString(R.string.tab_3);
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Да в том то и проблема, что нужны были именно `View`... Но все равно пришлось перейти на фрагменты, без них не работало.